# how to Copy and Delete files in Windows 10 drives from Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, copy, copy-and-paste

I am using windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on the same Laptop. I have mostly data stored in my windows 10 drives but now I am using Ubuntu often.
I have access to windows drives but only I can read and copy to Ubuntu folder.

actually I want to Manage (Copy and Delete) files stored in windows drive from ubuntu. and Copy all new data in windows drive from Ubuntu.

kindly guide me the easiest way to manage windows drive from ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mounting Windows partition inside Ubuntu (dual boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959743/mounting-windows-partition-inside-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 1):

The above answer didn't solve my problem but I kept searching and now I solve my problem and want to share Solutions here and Maybe this Solution will help others.

First Run command
    "killall nautilus"

Second Run
    "sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdd1"

Replace sdd1 with your drive and thats it.

Comment: +1. Thanks for sharing your solution. Maybe [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043163/how-to-change-ownership-and-permissions-of-automatically-mounted-hdd/1043300?r=SearchResults&s=12|8.0690#1043300) and links from it will add some details that can be useful also for new users.

Comment: you can solve this permantly with the fstab file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to shutdown the windows 10 properly first in order to access the drives from ubuntu. There are two ways to do this. In both ways you have to log in to your windows 10. The first is permanent and you have to disable fast boot/fast shutdown from settings. Then restart your pc and log in to ubuntu. You should be able to access your drives from File Browser.

The second way is a shortcut. That is first log into windows and restart. After restarting, log into ubuntu and you should be able to access the drives. Note that if you again access windows then you have to restart (not shutdown) and access ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: thanks for your Reply. I did all you mentioned but it didn't work for me.  but i just Run Command in Terminal    "Killall nautilus"    and then i Run second Command    "sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdd1"    where i change sdd1 with my own drive and it work perfectly. Now every time i start my ubuntu my other drives of Windows are already writeable.

Answer (score 0):

Go in Ubuntu to the file system. (via nautlilus - nemo or terminal)
Go to the folder media or mnt (depends)  and open this folder as administrator. (most easy methode is via nautilus or nemo)
You will see the drives of Windows.  For each file change the ownerchip  from root to you own name. Close everyting and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply but i tried it changed ownership and changed permission but no Luck.

Comment: I still can use My Windows Partition named "Main" i can use data but I can't save new data or delete old files in this Partition "Main".  is there any software which can help me.