# I use Ubuntu 22.04 and the error message: Permissions do not allow pasting files in this directory. When I copy file from Ubuntu disk to windows

Tags: dual-boot

Why does this error appear when I try to copy files from my Ubuntu partition to my Windows partition?

Comment: Did you disable fast boot on Windows? If not, do it and try again. There is no need for `sudo`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: Did you search for a solution already, and if so why did that not work? For instance, [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1181821/134479), [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/959743/134479) or several other questions on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mounting Windows partition inside Ubuntu (dual boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959743/mounting-windows-partition-inside-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: No this not answer my question

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you do not have permission to copy these files. Try running it as sudo.

Open Terminal, type `sudo nautilus` then navigate the the directory with the files to copy, copy them. then paste them to the directory that you want to copy them to.

You can also do this from your command line. Open your terminal, `cd` to the directory with the files that you want to copy in them, run `sudo cp -v file1 file 2 file 3 ... directorytopastefilesto` The `-v` attribute just makes it so that you can see the output of the copy command. In place of `...` put names of other files that you will copy.

Comment: Yes but I want to make it when i edit my files using vs code like laravel project but I can't make it